# React + Typescript: reactjs doesn't fail compiling on typescript error

Tags: reactjs, typescript

starting from some point recently, my React compiling doesn't fail on the obvious typescript error, it has been working for a long time, and I forgot what config matters, does anybody have a clue?

As the screenshot shows, I updated the parameter type with a new field, VS code actually captured the missing field, but ReactJS still let go, I definitely want it fails the build so that I can fix all places accordingly.

```
  # yarn start script
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
```

(note: I didn't upgrade reactjs or typescript versions recently)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What does your `ts.config` looks like ?

Comment: Thanks @Johan! This is my tsconfig.json

https://gist.github.com/shawncao/6f605ef79ae920f9fd9f25146d5d7d4e